# Service Bus after message expiration

Tags: azureservicebus

I am a beginner with the azure service bus. the message sent to the queue with time to live. and when the message expired I want to receive it and call some methods to be done. how can i do that?

Comment: http://pmichaels.net/2017/07/02/azure-service-bus-send-e-mail-message-timeout/

Answer (score 2):

There's an option you could try - enabling dead-lettering on expired messages.

**[QueueDescription.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.enabledeadletteringonmessageexpiration?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueDescription_EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration) Property**

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether this queue has dead letter support when a message expires.

This will send a message to the queue's DLQ. But that means if you have a message dead-lettered for another reason (such as delivery count exceeding the maximum), you'd also see that message in the DLQ. Fortunately, there's a reason property/header (`DeadLetterReason`). For messages moved to the DLQ because of TTL expiry, the [value will be `TTLExpiredException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#exceeding-timetolive).

Answer (score 0):

> and when the message expired I want to receive it and call some methods to be done. how can i do that?.

As I known, in order to pick up the dead letter messages, your could construct  the queue receiver just as the normal queue. If you have a queue named "myqueue" then the DLQ path would look like `myqueue/$DeadLetterQueue`.

Here is the sample code written in C# for receiving message from DLQ:

```
var deadletterReceiver = await receiverFactory.CreateMessageReceiverAsync(
    QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(queueName), ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
while (true)
{
    var msg = await deadletterReceiver.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.Zero);
    if (msg != null)
    {
        foreach (var prop in msg.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Key, prop.Value);
        }
        await msg.CompleteAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to [DeadletterQueue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-servicebus-messaging-samples/tree/master/DeadletterQueue). Also, you could follow the official tutorial about [get-started-with-queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) and choose your development language.